# FCM duplicated messages from php to iOS flutter app

Tags: php, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Cloud Message for a Flutter app.

I try to trigger a push notification with php code. It give me a success: 1 result, but on my device I always receive 2 message with the same title&body but different message ID (which is provided by google firebase).

I double checked, that I trigger this function only once on a server side.

my code on the server

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$msg = array
    (
          'body'  => $message,
          'title' => $title,
                  'badge' => 1,/*Default sound*/
                  'sound' => 'default',
    );
$fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids' => $id,
            'notification'  => $msg
        );

$fields = json_encode ( $fields );

$apiKey = 'XXXXXXX'; //IOS

$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key='.$apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
    echo $result;
```

---

I tried to trigger this from Terminal, which worked fine, and sent only 1 message. My terminal code:

```
DATA='{"notification": {"body": "this is a body","title": "this is a title"}, "priority": "high", "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "id": "1", "status": "done"}, "to": "MYDEVICETOKEN"}'
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "$DATA" -H "Authorization: key=XXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: hello, facing the same issue. did  you figure out the problem?

Comment: Do you try the call in web browser? The Chrome trigger twice the code, that is why the messages duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently seems like a flutter issue.
As a workaround for now u can create a boolean and trigger it like so:

```
class _SomethScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {

  bool onNotificationTrigger = false;
...

_fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> response) async {
        setState(() {
          onNotificationTrigger = !onNotificationTrigger;

          if (onNotificationTrigger)
           // Do Something
        });
      },
...
```

Comment: Can we get an updated version of this example please?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but it was in React-native. Maybe it can help you. The problem was having two services responsible for receiving notifications\messages in AndroidManifest.

Comment: I also had this issue on iOS devices, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

For me, works on upgrade to:

- Flutter version 1.17.5
- Firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16